# set background image url from Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I'm making BlackJack in JavaScript, Jquery, CSS and HTML. but I'm stuck with showing the card.
I need to place them into a array like:

```
var imgArray = new Array("images/harten/harten2.png","images/harten/harten2");
```

now I want to change the background-image from a div I did it this way:

```
    $('#cardplace1').css("background-size", "contain");
$('#cardplace1').css("background-image", "url(imgArray[0])");
```

for some weird reason it won't work, any tips?

Thanks !

Comment: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dUjUF/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
 $('#cardplace1').css("background-image", "url('" + imgArray[0] + "')");
```

You can set in single statement like,

```
$('#cardplace1').css({
    "background-image" : "url('" + imgArray[0] + "')",
    "background-size" : "contain"
});
```

Comment: Then the console (in firefox) gives the error:
ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side

Comment: Try, `$('#cardplace1').css("background-image", "url('" + imgArray[0] + "')");` this once

Comment: $('#cardplace1').css("background-image", "url('" + imgArray[0] + "')");

Worked perfectly, THANKS ALOT !