# Loading a css background image from jquery array

Tags: jquery, css, arrays, image, background

I am trying to change the background image of a div by loading it from an array of images. I already looked up the syntax on other StackOverflow threads, and I thought this should work:

```
 var pictures = ['pic1.jpg', 'pic2.jpg', 'pic3.jpg'];
 mainPhoto.css("background-image", "url(' + pictures[0] + ')";
```

But it's definitely not working. In fact it's making the rest of my code behave very strangely, so I just commented out for now. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [set background image url from Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891835/set-background-image-url-from-array)

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking at my code for so long I didn't even spot the missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a syntax error :

```
var pictures = ['pic1.jpg', 'pic2.jpg', 'pic3.jpg'];
mainPhoto.css('background-image', 'url(' + pictures[0] +')');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
mainPhoto.css("background-image", "url(" + pictures[0] + ")");
                                                            ^-- also missing this
```

Just string concatenation issue, mixing `"` with `'` and missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: This still have a syntax error :) You missed the last ) (of $.css() ).